# Using withWidth HOC from material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, server-side-rendering, higher-order-components

I'm using version `3.9.2` of Material UI and I'm trying to use `widthWith` HOC in a SSR app.

With the following code, if I disable Javascript in the debugger options of Chrome Developer Tools, everything works as expected (that is, the `hello world!` string is being displayed):

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Hello World!</div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

If I simply add the `withWidth` HOC, it returns an empty component as stated in the [docs](https://material-ui.com/layout/breakpoints/):

> As window.innerWidth is unavailable on the server, we default to rendering an empty component during the first mount.

But there is a `withWidth` config option to set a default value for this:

```
import React from 'react';
import withWidth from '@material-ui/core/withWidth';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Hello World!</div>
    );
  }
}

export default withWidth(
  [{
    initialwidth: 'lg',
  }],
)(App);
```

However the problem remains the same and no output is being displayed.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option should be `initialWidth` (uppercase `W`) instead of `initialwidth` and the square brackets in the documentation are just to indicate that the options are optional. The correct syntax would look like:

```
export default withWidth({initialWidth: 'lg'})(App);
```